# How to send a delete request mutation with local storage

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3, vuex

I am building a recipe application. I am trying to create a button that deletes a previously added recipe from Vuex with local storage. My issue is when ever I click the delete button it doesn't delete the recipe that I have selected, instead it deletes the most recent recipe that I have added to my vuex array.

This is the code to my vuex store

```
    recipes: [
      {
        slug: '',
        title: '',
        description: '',
        ingredients: [
          
        ],
        method: [
          
        ]
      },
      {
        slug: '',
        title: '',
        description: '',
        ingredients: [
          
        ],
        method: [
         
        ]
      },
    ]
  },
  getters: {
  },
  mutations: {
    loadStore() {
      if(localStorage.getItem('store')) {
          try {
              this.replaceState(JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('store')));
          }
          catch(e) {
              console.log('Could not initialize store', e);
          }
      }
  },
    ADD_RECIPE (state, recipe){
      state.recipes.push(recipe)
    },
    //This is a delete request
    delete_Recipe(state, recipe){
   let index = state.recipes.indexOf(recipe);
      state.recipes.splice(index,1);
     },
  },
```

And this is my code in which I am trying to add a button that deletes my selected recipe

```
<template>
  <div class="recipe">
    <router-link to="/">&lt; Back</router-link>
    <h1>{{ recipe.title }}</h1> 
     <p class="desc">{{recipe.description}}</p>
   <hr />
    <div class="ingredients">
<h3> Ingredients</h3>
<ul>
    <li v-for="(ingredient, i) in recipe.ingredients" :key="i">
    {{ingredient }}
</li>
</ul>
    </div>
    <hr />
    <div class="method">
<h3> Instructions</h3>
<ol>
    <li v-for="(step, i) in recipe.method" :key="i">
    <span v-html="cleanText(step)"></span>
</li>
</ol>
    </div>
    <button @click="deleteRecipe">Delete Recipe</button>


  </div>
</template>

<script>
import $store from '../store'

export default {
    
    setup(){

        const deleteRecipe = () => {
            $store.commit('delete_Recipe')

        }
        return {deleteRecipe}

    },
    computed: {
        recipe(){
            return this.$store.state.recipes.find(recipe => recipe.slug === this.$route.params.slug)
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The immediate problem is inside the delete request. When `Array.indexOf` doesn't find the item inside the array, it returns -1. `Array.splice(-1, 1)` removes the last item in the array.

Consider passing the index to the delete request. Better yet, give each recipe a unique ID and pass that when deleting a recipe.